# How to convert a normal map into a curvature map (per pixel curvature)

Tags: texturing, compositing-nodes

I am trying to generate a sharp curvature / cavity map in the compositor from a normal map but I don't know the node setup.

Here is my reference: http://polycount.com/discussion/comment/2273084/#Comment_2273084

Comment: Instead of editing original post with solution please write an answer with node setup and steps you took to achieve that, thanks!

Comment: @DanylBekhoucha Please write your own answer. Please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Generate a curvature map from a normal map**

Here are two node setups you can use to generate a curvature or cavity map from a normal map, they use the same amount of nodes and give the same result. You can download all the node setups here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bixkxs6cSes-J9GVwDeIP7pW2OnGNhYd/view?usp=sharing

Link of the image used: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1wP1Y8dmh8aVmN6VUpYMU02Q28/view?usp=sharing (it is from the Unity Store "Rock and Boulders 2" free pack: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/props/exterior/rock-and-boulders-2-6947).

First node setup (easier to understand):
[image]

Second node setup:
[image]

You can also use this Emboss node setup to generate the curvature map: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/102727/23134

You must set your normal map as Linear in the "n" menu to make the value nodes works properly. To export your curvature to another software like Photoshop add a gamma node at 2.2, don't use it to work on it in Blender.

I have written in the frame +R X- meaning that the red channel must use a -0.5 translate in X and it's the opposite with a positive direction the image must be inverted.

The Pixel width determine the thickness of the lines, it is then divided by 2 and inverted one time for each channel so it moves in X +0.5 and -0.5 for the red channel and Y +0.5 and -0.5 for the green channel.

**How does it works?**

The color channels of the normal maps create a lighting effect, for example the red channel gives the impression that the textures is lighten from the right and the green from the top. By moving the texture in the direction of the shadows, so for the red channel with the lighting coming from the right we move the texture to the left and by inverting the image to invert the lighting direction we move it to the right, then the images are both combined to create a black contour from the expanded shadows. Three Linear Light node at 0.5 are added, one to combine the red channels, one for the blue channels then one for both color channels.

Then the gamma node converts the image from sRGB to Linear.
Blender works with sRGB images, when you set an image to Linear in the "n" menu this tells Blender that the image imported is in Linear mode and must be converted in sRGB to work with it.

**Things you can do with the curvature:**

- you can overlay it with a smooth curvature map, see how to generate it here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/100637/23134
- you can multiply it with an ambient occlusion map for a diffuse grayscale (in PBR do not multiply it).
- you can fake an hand painted effect by adding a color ramp node: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/90153/23134
- See how to create a Dota asset with this texture: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/101830/23134
- you can bake the normal map in 32 bit Float exported in OpenEXR Float Full to improve the curvature map, you can then export your curvature map in 8 bits TGA.
- you can bake the normal map in an high resolution then generate the curvature map and scale the image down to get an anti-aliasing effect.
- if the normal map is baked in DirectX instead of OpenGL you will need to use a Converter > Separated RGBA and invert the green channel then plug everything to a Converter > Combine RGBA.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in real-time in Cycles?

Comment: No, the only software able to do that is Knald: https://docs.knaldtech.com/doku.php?id=curvature_maps_knald_1.1

Comment: Sure this is possible in real time in cycles by building 3x3 edge detection convolution kernel.

Comment: Could this be used to generate curvature from the Normal output of a Cycles render layer? Obviously it will need some adjustment.

Comment: No because there is no translate node to reproduce this node setup.

Comment: @DanylBekhoucha I do not mean in the material, I mean in the compositor. This current setup is expecting the sorts of colors from a normal map, which is different from the cycles renderlayer normal pass.

Comment: Note: I have updated the node setup, it's easier to create there is no order for the inputs and it is closer to Substance Designer. I am currently working on the Curvature Smooth effect.

Comment: @DanylBekhoucha you can translate using Mapping node in Cycles, the group is reproducible.

Comment: You can't translate the normals of your mesh and you can only use object space normal which won't work correctly.

Comment: Can you recreate the result in the shader editor?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it based on the mesh and not a normal map.
[image]