# Can normal maps be edited after creation?

Tags: normal-map

I have some normal maps and want to edit them. Is there an alternative to do so without going through the process of baking it again, such as painting?

Comment: One option could be to extract the height information into a bump map as in this answer : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/90276/29586. Once you have that you can edit it in and later use it as the input to a bump node to convert back to a normal.