# How to bake a curvature map in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, baking

I want to bake a curvature map in Cycles but not by using the pointiness node which is dependent of the vertex density and not with a normal map to cavity ( [How to convert a normal map into a curvature map](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52902/how-to-convert-a-normal-map-into-a-cavity-map) ) because it creates artefacts.

I want to create a Concavity map that generates dark areas in concave shapes. Suzanne should bake like this (baked in Knald):

[image]

And i need to combine it with a Convexity map that highlights the peaks like this (baked in Knald):

[image]

I want the closest possible bake to the images i have posted above. I have used the Suzanne's default scale and a plane to bake it.

Comment: did you try "dirty vertex colors"? http://adaptivesamples.com/2013/08/07/commonly-ignored-feature-6-dirty-vertex-colours/

Comment: It's like the pointiness node, the quality depend of the vertex density. A curvature map works with every topology.

Comment: I know it's late, and I don't have a proven, tested answer right now, but the way to handle this would be to bake world space normals and then check the dot products of each sample with its neighbors in the compositor.  Where the net dot products are negative, you have convexity; where they're positive, you have concavity; where they're zero, you're either flat or have negative (saddle) curvature.  That'd be in UV space, but you could resample based on world space lookups from baked world space and correct (except if you crossed a seam.)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this helps. Baking an Edge map Using Ambient Occlusion https://youtu.be/RhMEBKuPYXY

Comment: It's a solution, but having to invert the normales of an high poly with millions of triangles takes a lot of computing time/power.

Comment: Also a thin cylinder will create errors, his planar faces will generate occlusion because they will be close to each other and the thinkness low. The concavity and convexity generates informations based on the angles only.