# Is it possible to generate curvature mask from geometry normal?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

I want the smooth and sharp curvature mask of geometry so that I can use it in a `mix color > factor`. I know we can do with `Geometry > Pointiness` but it's not giving the desired results.

[image]

I found this solution that uses a normal map to convert into a curvature map but uses the compositor.

[How to convert a normal map into a curvature map (per pixel curvature)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52902/how-to-convert-a-normal-map-into-a-curvature-map-per-pixel-curvature)

[How to get a smooth curvature map from a normal map?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89278/how-to-get-a-smooth-curvature-map-from-a-normal-map)

I wonder if it is possible to use the `Geometry > Normal` to generate a curvature mask in the shader editor. and I want e.g. [smooth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgVw4.png) and [sharp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FiGB.jpg) curvature that can be controlled via a `Value` node.

[image]

*Value = 0* : Smooth Curvature

*interpolated*

*Value = 1* : Sharp Curvature

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, do you want to read or set the curvature? Also some clear explanation what curvature even is, in the context of circles represented as polygons, would be nice. Depending on these details a solution could be trivial (lerping between normal and true normal based on the "Value") or impossible (how to calculate a curvature, without preprocessing, in the context where you access just a single point?)

Comment: Do you want geometry/pointiness, or do you want the curvature maps that you've linked?  The two are very different.  It may be possible to recreate pointiness via a combination of geometry nodes and shader work, but it is not possible to recreate the curvature maps you've linked, not live.  Baking textures would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this (showing the math of creating an edge map in the shader editor, not a "real" shader):

[image]

By playing around with the `Bevel`, `Color Ramp` and `Invert Color` Node you can highlight/mask different parts (e.g. edges) of your model.