# How to make sharp curvature mask?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

I made a curvature mask (smooth curvature).

[image]

Now how to get this result (I think it is called sharp curvature)?

[image]

Related to this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/309033/is-it-possible-to-generate-curvature-map-from-geometry-normal)